# Appropriate use of Authority in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify, authority

I'm following the Michael Hartl RoR tutorial, but implementing Rollify and Authority along the way. I've never used Authority before and I am wondering if the following before_action is appropriate for Authority use

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb 
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  .
  .
  .
  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end
end
```

would it be "good programming practice" to put the `def logged_in_user` inside of the ApplicationAuthorizer class for future use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be "good programming practice" to put `logged_in_user` inside `ApplicationAuthorizer`

No.

There is a [difference](https://serverfault.com/questions/57077/what-is-the-difference-between-authentication-and-authorization) between `Authentication` and `Authorization`:

- Authentication -- user logged in?
- Authorization    -- can user *do* this?

The difference is subtle but important - you'd expect authentication to happen *before* authorization, or at least independently.

A good analogy is *authentication* is when you get access to a secret party (password); *authorization* is which table you're able to sit at.

If you used one of the pre-rolled authentication systems ([`Devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or [`Sorcery`](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery)), you'd have your authentication handled, providing you with such helpers as [`user_signed_in?`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) etc.

---

To answer your question, your current pattern will suffice, considering you've rolled your own authentication.

If you were using `Devise`, you'd want to use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
authenticate :user do
  resource :profile, controller: :users, only: [:show, :update] #-> url.com/profile
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user.update update_params
  end
end
```

--

What you're trying to do is evaluate the `@user.id` against `current_user.id`:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Authority::UserAbilities
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]

  def edit
     @user = User.find params[:id]
     redirect_to root_path, notice: "Can't edit this user" unless current_user.can_edit?(@user)
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find params[:id]
    if current_user.can_update?(@user)
       @user.update ...
    else
      # redirect
    end
  end

  private

  def logged_in_user
    redirect_to login_url, error: "Please log in." unless logged_in?
  end
end

# app/authorizers/user_authorizer.rb
class UserAuthorizer < ApplicationAuthorizer

  def self.editable_by?(user)
    user.id = self.id
  end

  def self.updatable_by?(user)
    user.id = self.id
  end
end
```